# Getting only the most recent tweet - Monkeh Tweets

Tags: twitter, coldfusion

I'm using ColdFusion MonkehTweets component. But actually, all I'm trying to do is get the single most recent tweet for #allblacks.

Here is the URL MonkehTweets generates. I have blanked out the keys etc for the purposes of this post:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?checkheader=false&count=1&include_entities=true&lang=en&oauth_consumer_key=blah123&oauth_nonce=blah123&oauth_signature=blah123&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1378795729&oauth_token=blah123&oauth_version=1.0&q=from%253Aallblacks

This constantly returns the first Tweet on 7th September at https://twitter.com/allblacks
instead of the latest tweet.

Not sure what's going on and would appreciate some help please.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets you could use the optional parameter `result_type` with value `recent`. That should return only the most recent results in the response.

And I'd use @allblacks for the `q` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I did see that result_type param and tried it unsuccessfully. Using @allblacks gets tweets that are not created by allblacks unfortunately.

Comment: I've ended up using the twitter widget. It'll do for now.